# Zxing connection refused on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, zxing, production-environment

I'm using ZXing to decode my qr codes, it works fine on development, but on production after deploy it just works for five minutes or so and only if I restart the server, after that it just doesn't work, going through the log, this is what comes out:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (druby://127.0.0.1:51876 - #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)>):
1: <% provide(:title, "Updating...") %>
2: <input />
3: <% if (ZXing.decode "public/assets/#{current_user.user_name.downcase}_bdd.jpg").nil? %>
4:  <% flash.now[:notice] = "BDD invalid, change it!" %>
5:  <div class="actions_cambiar_bdd">
app/views/users/change_folios.html.erb:3:in 
`_app_views_users_change_folios_html_erb___206747123981808960_69821004639000'
```

I don't know what is going on, looking at it, I think that it cannot works its way out to my server that's why the connection refused, but the weird thing is that it works fine for a couple of minutes after the server is restarted, after that, nothing, I hope anyone can help me out. Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:**
Apparently after a while the port gets blocked or busy, i guess that is something to do with how zxing manage the port assign, here are some files of it:

**EDIT 2**

client.rb

```
require 'socket'
require 'drb'

module ZXing
  BIN = File.expand_path('../../../bin/zxing', __FILE__)

  class Client
    def self.new
      port = ENV['ZXING_PORT'] || find_available_port
      setup_drb_server(port) unless ENV['ZXING_PORT'] && responsive?(port)
      DRbObject.new_with_uri("druby://127.0.0.1:#{port}")
    end

    private

    def self.setup_drb_server(port)
      remote_client = IO.popen("#{ZXing::BIN} #{port}")
      sleep 0.5 until responsive?(port)
      at_exit { Process.kill(:INT, remote_client.pid) }
    end

    def self.responsive?(port)
      socket = TCPSocket.open('127.0.0.1', port)
      true
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
      false
    ensure
      socket.close if socket
    end

    def self.find_available_port
      server = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 0)
      server.addr[1]
    ensure
      server.close if server
    end
  end
end
```

I kind of get answered on github by one of the guys in the zxing project:

https://github.com/ecin/zxing.rb/issues/6

Shortly he gave me the advice to export from my code the ZXING_PORT const, but it did not solve it, the number on the ZXING_PORT gets the same treatment, it works for a couple of minutes, and then the same mistake, only this time with the ZXING_PORT

```
ActionView::Template::Error (druby://127.0.0.1:ZXING_PORT - #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)>):
```

I'm considering the options to either somehow "reserve" the port or socket so no process can take it or find a way to reload the gem on the production environment on every request.

Which option should i take? Which one is the more appropied or the more plausible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i finally got it to work, i put the code on boot.rb, just before the gems are loaded

```
require 'rubygems'

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['PORT_NUMBER'] = "4333"
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)


require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```